# How to rigorously prove that set of reciprocal elements of a class in a group forms a class in itself?

Tags: group-theory

Let's say K is a class of Group G, and let's say $a_{i}$ 's  are its reciprocal elements. How to rigorously prove that the reciprocal elements form a class themselves ?

Comment: Could you provide additional context? I'm not sure what you mean by a class in this setting.

Comment: Let's suppose Ks are the conjugacy classes.

Comment: I am not sure if Hamermesh means the same thing, but it seems that he's contextually talking about conjugacy classes in his group theory book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $K$ is a conjugacy equivalence class.  In other words, for some $a$,
$$
K=\{gag^{-1}:g\in G\}.
$$
The inverses of elements in $K$ are
$$
K'=\{(gag^{-1})^{-1}:g\in G\}=\{ga^{-1}g^{-1}:g\in G\}.
$$
Therefore, $K'$ is the conjugacy equivalence class for $a^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, there it is. My line of reasoning missed that $a^{-1}$s belonged to the group G itself. (It should be, by definition of a group). Thanks!